# Getting extra information using Containable?

Tags: cakephp, model, associations

I have 4 models:

`Company` model:

```
class Company extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = "User";
}
```

`User` model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = "Company";
    public $hasMany = array("Post", "Comment");
}
```

`Post` model:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = "User";
    public $hasMany = "Comment";
}
```

`Comment` model:

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array("User", "Post");
}
```

In `PostsController.php`, I have:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id) {
        //$post = $this->Post->findById($id); // does not retrieve extra information
        //$post = $this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id), 'recursive' => 2)); // does retrieve too much extra information
        $post = $this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id), 'contain' => array('Company.nom'))); // Warning (512): Model "Post" is not associated with model "Company"
        $this->set('post', $post);
    }
}
```

On my `Post` view, here's the debug when I use recursive way :

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [content] => Hello world !
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [company_id] => 2
            [name] => John DOE
            [Company] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [nom] => Apple
                )

            [Post] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [content] => Hello world !
                        )

                )

            [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 1
                            [content] => This is a comment
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 1
                            [content] => This is another comment
                        )

                )

        )

    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [content] => This is a comment
                    [User] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [company_id] => 2
                            [name] => John DOE
                        )

                    [Post] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [content] => Hello world !
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [content] => This is another comment
                    [User] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [company_id] => 2
                            [name] => John DOE
                        )

                    [Post] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [content] => Hello world !
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How can I use Containable the good way to retrieve `Company` informations? 
My question seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326802/getting-some-extra-information-from-a-comment/).

Comment: the other question you linked is the exact solution to your problem, so, could you update your question with how did you implemented the solutions? maybe you missed something

Comment: Ok, I managed with the "recursive" way. But I still don't understand how to do with the "containable" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

within your models, like

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

You had to follow the link given in the answer to get that. I'll [paste it here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) for you.

And the find would be like

```
$post = $this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id), 
                                         'contain' => array('User' => array('Company'))));
```

Should read the docs for that, it has a lot of examples.